# Java - ThreadFactory memory leak?

Tags: multithreading, memory-leaks

This code:

```
    while (true) {
        new ThreadFactory() {
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

make the JVM go out of memory very quickly.

Why?

Comment: You have an **infinite** loop that creates objects: what do you expect?

Comment: I expect the GC to collect the unused references.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `ThreadFactory`. You will see similar effects for most other classes, too.

Comment: @ben: How will GC know that they are unused? You never exit the scope they exist in.

Comment: @ben I have updated my previous answer as I consider it was incorrect. Please review it if it is still topical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to run this code with JRE 1.7.0_60 x86_64 on Windows 7 with default options and here are the results:

1. Author's code being run as is doesn't seem to perform any allocation at all, most likely because JIT detects unused references;
2. Modified version of code that outputs created `threadFactory`s to `System.out` results in "saw-like" heap usage pattern:

[image]

Which means that both allocation and garbage collection takes place.

Back to your question: I think you missed some significant parts of the code, or put -Xmx to extremely low value, or some other reason. The code you posted is ok, though.